# What is better: A general dashboard area or one area for each context?

Tags: dashboard, data-analysis, analytics

I´m working on the UX area of a company that works with a web application suite related with [BPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management), [ECM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_content_management), PFMEA, and a lot of other "letters".
Now we are wornking on the integration, the  analysis of the all content and the relations with each other.

My question is: **This action (analysys relations) should be presented in a new area default (like a dashboard/cockpit) ou create an analysis area in each application?**

e.g.:

1. The manager will access the "integration screen" and chose the
   applications (component) to see the relations.
2. The manager will access the component and go to the Analysis Area
   and chose the others relations.

It makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that analysis is a broad subject and anything can be analyzed. The main point of analyzing is to have a valuable information after analyzing process.

Especially, in real time businesses, some analysis may have influence on the user actions. In these cases, I think that the information should be close to action page and component itself (if you are transparent to your client). Like, having the price estimation of a stock can be placed near buy/sell button with actual price.

Information and analysis can be also filtered by changing user behavior. If user only see positive estimations of a stock price but not the negative one, it will be totally a different experience than having both negative and positive at the same time.  In other words, the purpose of showing any analysis is also as important as the location of the analysis itself.

Some users also want to only analyze the overall system intensively. I think that having a analysis section with following game theory milestones (simple to extended) will work fine.

In short, **showing the relevant information on the right context will increase the overall experience. In addition to this, having an extensive analysis section in which user can do extensive analysis will enable user if he needs an extensive results**

Answer (score 0):

The best solution depends on context: users, tasks, environment (think of display size, too).

In general, I think of more smart way. This way is used widely both in a digital devices (MFUs, digital cameras, etc.) and software world.

All the indexes are divided on two parts: primary and secondary. Primary indexes are displayed on a integrated dashboard, while secondary ones are accessible via component.

Some examples:
[image]
*Digital camera dashboard displays primary settings*
.

[image]
*A ton of settings in components' menu*
.

[image]
*Google Analytics display dashboard as default screen and provide access to components via left menu*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll really end up needing is a general dashboard area **AND** areas that are specific to each context.

The general dashboard is useful for pointing a user to the specific areas that need attention.  The context specific areas are useful for actually completing whatever work needs to be done.